# Replace second occurence of every character in a string, Python

Tags: python, string

I want to replace every second occurence of a character from only a string as input. Using only the .replace method.

For example:

input: asdasdasdasd

output should be: asdASDasdasd

```
def main(string):
   for char in string:
      string.replace(char, char.upper())
   return string
```

Im relatively new to Python and I can't wrap my head around what to do.

Comment: `replace` returns a new string

Comment: All right, but then I can make a new string y and use that. But how can I replace only the second occurence of the character?

Comment: If `input_1="aaa"`,  what is the expected `output_1`? If `input_2="aaaaaa"`,  what is the expected `output_2`?

Comment: output_1 = 'aAa'. Output_2 = 'aAaaaa'

Comment: @Mart if `input='AAA', Then what?

Comment: the input is only lowercase

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, you can use a dictionary and make the second occurrence of each character to uppercase:

```
def upper_case_second_occurrence(s):
    d = {}
    s = list(s)
    for i, c in enumerate(s):
        d[c] = d.get(c, 0) + 1
        if d[c] == 2:
            s[i] = c.upper()
    return "".join(s)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(upper_case_second_occurrence("aaa"))
    print(upper_case_second_occurrence("aaaaaa"))
    print(upper_case_second_occurrence("asdasdasdasd"))
```

Output:

```
aAa
aAaaaa
asdASDasdasd
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Do you also have an answer when I can only use the .replace method for example?

Comment: The doc for `str.replace` mentions it replaces all or the first `n` occurrences of a character from a string with a new character https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace . I do not think you can only use `replace` method in your scenario.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```py
def main(s):
    l = []
    string = ''
    y = True
    for a in s:
        if a in l and y:
            string+=a.upper()
            l.remove(a)
            if not len(l):
                l = ''
            continue
        try:
            l.append(a)
        except AttributeError:
            y = False
        string+=a
    return(string)

print(main('asdasdasdasd')) # → asdASDasdasd
print(main('aaa')) # → aAa
print(main('aaaaa')) # → aAaaa
print(main('AAA') # → AAA
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `.count()`:

```
def main(string):
    new_string = ''
    for char in string:
        if new_string.lower().count(char) == 1: # This line checks if the count of char is 1 or not. If yes, then it appends the uppercase letter of char
            new_string += char.upper()
        else:
            new_string += char
    return new_string
```

Output:

```
main('asdasdasdasd')
'asdASDasdasd'
main('aaaaaa')
'aAaaaa'
main('aaa')
'aAa'
```